# How to create a select using knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

I am trying to create a select bind of an object to a drop down list but i keep getting nothing.

Html

```
<select data-bind="options: defaultConvocationVagues,
                               optionsText: vagueDesc,
                               value: selectedVague">
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
function vague(id,desc)
{
   this.vagueID = ko.observable(id);
 this.vagueDesc = ko.observable(desc);
}
var ViewModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   this.defaultConvocationVagues = ko.observableArray();
   this.selectedVague = ko.observable();
   self.defaultConvocationVagues.push(new Vague(1,'wave1'));
   self.defaultConvocationVagues.push(new Vague(2,'wave2'));
   self.defaultConvocationVagues.push(new Vague(3,'wave3'));
};
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jseb04/v5jm4prn/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `function vague(id, desc)` but you use it like `new Vague(1, 'wave')`. Keep the casing consistent.

The main issue is how you set `optionsText: vagueDesc`. optionsText should be set to the property name (as a string). So you need to change it to `optionsText: 'vagueDesc'`.